# How to setup google cloud loggin for rails app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

The default rails production setup seems to be overwriting stackdriver logger configuration.

The [stackdriver gem documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/main/stackdriver#using-ruby-on-rails) entails that nothing else is need in order to get it to work with ruby and rails but by default a rails app has this configuration on the `production.rb`. I'm setting `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true`.

```rb
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

What's the ideal setup? Logs are not displayed if this setup is removed.

Comment: for [Setting Up Cloud Logging for Ruby](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby) you can refer to this documentation.

Answer (score -1):

For the use of Ruby with Stackdriver logging see this documentation on [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-ruby) and [Setting Up Cloud Logging for Ruby](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby).

Here's also a reference documentation for the APIs [Module: Google::Cloud::Logging](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-logging/latest/Google/Cloud/Logging.html)

Comment: The documentation says that nothing else is needed when using it with ruby on rails but loading the gem. But something must be done since it's not working. Should I replaced rails logger when it supposed to be setup automatically? No need to use STDOUT anymore? how about the formatter? The docs are incomplete

Comment: It's Feb 2024, following the documentation is not enough. When enabling stackdriver in development with `config.google_cloud.use_logging = true` it fails with `log_to_stdout': undefined method 'broadcast_to' for #<Google::Cloud::Logging::Logger`.

Comment: For those having issues with this as well, I hope to find a solution with a fresh question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936668/how-to-make-google-stackdriver-works-with-rails-7-1